# How to export and destructure an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I have reducer keys

```
const foo = {
    ADD: 1,
    REDO: 2,
    UNDO: 3,
}
```

And I want to export it but when importing, I should be able to do

```
import MyComponent, { ADD, REDO } from '../bar'
```

The only problem is that I already another thing to export

Here is what my code looks like

```
export default Component
export { Bar, ...foo} // can't do this, gives me syntax error
```

Comment: Don't export an anonymous object (that's what you are doing, that syntax is not destructuring - destructuring is only on the left hand side of an assignment). Exports need a name so you **MUST** `export Bar; export foo`. You **CANNOT** `export {}` or `export []` or `export function () {}` etc.

Comment: @slebetman so if I want to import my keys the way I showed, I need to do `export const ADD = 1; export const REDO = 2; export const UNDO = 3;`? That is the only way?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> export { Bar, ...foo} // can't do this, gives me syntax error

Yes, that is a syntax error. Exports need names so you must do something like the following:

```
export Bar;
export foo;
```

But this requires you to import `foo`:

```
import { foo } from '../bar'
```

If you want to import `ADD`, `REDO` etc they must be their own named objects:

```
export const ADD = 1;
export const REDO = 2;
export const UNDO = 3;
```

Comment: Can you do `export { foo as default, bar }`?